# how to save my given dictionary in python to sqlite and how to create table for it as i am facing problem creating table for dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

```py
dict = {
    'Customer': {
        'token': 001,
        'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 11, 20, 40),
        'last_visit_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 7,24, 11, 20, 40),
        'purchase_amount': 1000, 
        'quantity': 4,
        'items': {
            'a': 200,
            'b': 300,
            'c': 250,
            'd': 250
        }
    }
}
```

how to create table for this in sqlite python and store it in sql db

Comment: why does your `items` key have two keys as `b`?

Comment: also why is the token field `001` without quotes? do you want it to be an integer or a string?

Comment: 'token': 001 = integer
'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 26, 11, 20, 40), = timestamp
‘purchase_amount': 1000 = integer
‘quantity': 4 = integer
'items': {'a': 200, 'b': 300, 'c': 250, 'd': 250} = dictionary @Debdut Goswami

Comment: sorry i wrote 'b' key twice in item, it is d

Comment: Please provide your code attempt. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure is pretty straightforward. Simply add the higher level keys to one table and create a separate table for Item and make it a one-to-one relationship. I have attached the database diagram below.

[image: database structure]

If you want the sql query, then

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
  `token` int PRIMARY KEY,
  `timestamp` timestamp,
  `last_visited_time` timestamp,
  `purchase_amount` int,
  `quantity` int,
  `item` Items
);

CREATE TABLE `Items` (
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` int,
  `b` int,
  `c` int,
  `d` int
);

ALTER TABLE `Items` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`item`);
```

Comment: yes perfect thank you. '`id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT' got me error so i used '`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT' and it worked @DebdutGoswami